# Can I use the same regressors for Instrumental variables and the outcome variable?

Tags: regression, instrumental-variables, research-design, two-step-estimation

I'm reading a research paper that uses an IV, they regress A, and B, to estimate C, then they use estimated C and actual B to regress on D an outcome variable. This seems to violate the only through conditions for using IV estimation. Can someone confirm if I can include B in both regressions and why or why not? https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/19/1/45/1578805, the paper is Faulkender and Petersen ('06) "Does the Source of Capital Affect Capital Structure?"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper? A time series analysis may do this for a particular reason, but we'd need to see the original source to see if that's the case.

Comment: I've added the link to the paper in question, thank you!